# Azure Functions Connection Monitoring

Tags: c#, azure, sockets, connection, azure-functions

My function app is using huge HTTP requests frequently. And so I got an error following

```
Only one usage of each socket address is normally permitted
```

And function app will automatically shut down immediately for a few minutes after that. I searched about this and understood that Opening a new connection in each restSharp request caused that. And the better solution is to open only one HttpClient as static. So I changed the function to use a static HttpClient for all requests.

Now I want to know this change is working fine or not. I checked connections in the azure matrics but it always showing count "30". But it was the same in the case of RestSharp also. Somebody please help me to understand analyzing connections graph.
See the image

[image]
[image]

Any help is appreciated..

Comment: You are graphing average rate over a long period of time.  Most Request last very short periods of time (seconds) so looking at hours is not going to give realistic statics of any improvements.

Comment: @jdweng I checked 30 min period and I can see connections graph showing between 30 to 100. But I can see the average connections are gradually increasing per time. Why this increasing. Will this cause the socket connection issue again.

Comment: the use cmd.exed >Netstat -a which will give current connections and see it the connection are actually increasing.

Comment: @jdweng Can we run this command in azure function.?

Comment: See following : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f498f822-7c77-478a-ba12-887136ce39df/how-to-view-tcp-connections-for-azure-web-app?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

Comment: @Sumith Jose, did you get a chance to try below response?

Comment: @HarshitaSingh-MSFT Thanks, Can you check the comment.

Answer (score 1):

As far as the error message is concerned, if you have only 30 connections, it should not be an issue according to [this](https://help.socketlabs.com/docs/how-to-fix-error-only-one-usage-of-each-socket-address-protocolnetwork-addressport-is-normally-permitted) article, until and unless you have some configuration set to 30 in [Function App's host.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json-v1#sample-hostjson-file).

Coming to creation of static instance of HttpClient, if not already using, you can use DI to inject **singleton** instance of `HttpClient` in `FunctionsStartup` -

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(MyNamespace.Startup))]

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHttpClient, HttpClient>();
        }
    }
}
```

Then, use your Client like below:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class MyHttpTrigger
    {
        private readonly IHttpClient _client;

        public MyHttpTrigger(IHttpClient httpClient)
        {
            this._client = httpClient;
        }

        [FunctionName("MyHttpTrigger")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            var response = await _client.GetAsync("https://microsoft.com");    
            return new OkObjectResult("Response from function with injected dependencies.");
        }
    }
}
```

For complete implementation and other details, you can visit - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection

### Edit:

For information about the metrics of Azure App service plans, you can refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-monitor#understand-metrics) doc.

It depends on what level you have made the HttpClient static, it is always a recommended practice to use DI for a singleton scenario.

As per the design of Function App, [it scales out automatically, even during periods of high load](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale). I am not sure about the first graph as it does not reflect aggregation. The second graph shows the average of the number of bound sockets existing in the sandboxes (w3wp.exe and its child processes), and as you mentioned and I understand there are huge outbound Http requests in your function app and they are gradually increasing, if this is the case when there are highest outbound requests (137 as per graph), then your graph of Azure Function App looks good. Please note that [the limit of **Connections** for each sand box of Free/Shared/Consumption is 600 and Basic+ Limit is Unlimited (VM limit still applies).](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox) If your outbound Http requests are going beyond these limits, then you will have to redesign Function App in such a way that it keeps the connections within these limits.

If you want to dig deeper in future, you can refer to [this](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox) document for detailed information about **Azure Function App Sandbox**. This document is maintained by PG regularly.

Comment: Hi @harshitasingh-msft. Yes, you're right 30 connection won't cause socket exhausting issue. And I didn't set any connection limits.  But I can see there is an increase in the graph when I changed to graph plotting to average. And currently, I'm not using function templates. But I hope creating a single HttpClient is also similar to inject singleton instance of HttpClient. I just added another graph of Can you check it. This increment has no difference when I use either restSharp or Static HttpClient. Is this normal behaviour or will this cause connection exhausting issue.

Comment: Which hosting plan have you chosen?

Comment: App Service plan- Standard

Comment: @Sumith Jose, if this response answers your query, pls mark it as answer for the community reference.